# How to exclude null value when using FsCheck Property attribute?

Tags: tdd, xunit.net, fscheck

I need to write a simple method that receives a parameter (e.g. a `string`) and does smth. Usually I'd end up with two tests. The first one would be a [guard clause](http://wiki.c2.com/?GuardClause). The second would validate the *expected* behavior (for simplicity, the method shouldn't fail):

```
[Fact]
public void DoSmth_WithNull_Throws()
{
    var sut = new Sut();
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() =>
        sut.DoSmth(null));
}

[Fact]
public void DoSmth_WithValidString_DoesNotThrow()
{
    var s = "123";
    var sut = new Sut();
    sut.DoSmth(s); // does not throw
}

public class Sut
{
    public void DoSmth(string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        // do smth important here
    }
}
```

When I try to utilize the [FsCheck](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/index.html) `[Property]` attribute to generate random data, `null` and numerous other random values are passed to the test which at some point causes NRE:

```
[Property]
public void DoSmth_WithValidString_DoesNotThrow(string s)
{
    var sut = new Sut();
    sut.DoSmth(s); // throws ArgumentNullException after 'x' tests
}
```

I realize that this is the entire idea of FsCheck to generate numerous random data to cover different cases which is definitely great.

Is there any elegant way to configure the `[Property]` attribute to exclude *undesired* values? (In this particular test that's `null`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FsCheck has some built-in types that can be used to signal specific behaviour, like, for example, that reference type values shouldn't be null. One of these is `NonNull<'a>`. If you ask for one of these, instead of asking for a raw string, you'll get no nulls.

In F#, you'd be able to destructure it as a function argument:

```
[<Property>]
let DoSmth_WithValidString_DoesNotThrow (NonNull s) = // s is already a string here...
    let sut = Sut ()
    sut.DoSmth s // Use your favourite assertion library here...
}
```

I think that in C#, it ought to look something like this, but I haven't tried:

```
[Property]
public void DoSmth_WithValidString_DoesNotThrow(NonNull<string> s)
{
    var sut = new Sut();
    sut.DoSmth(s.Get); // throws ArgumentNullException after 'x' tests
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no [NotNull] attribute for C# (at least I couldn't find it in the source code).

Comment: @SergeyShushlyapin It's not an attribute, it's a type. It's defined in `FsCheck`, not `FsCheck.Xunit`.

Comment: Ah, it's `No_n_Null`! I was looking for `No_t_Null`, my bad, sorry. Yes, it works. Thanks Mark!