# Using Property in fscheck with filtered items

Tags: c#, xunit, fscheck

I am just starting with FsCheck and wanted to dig a little deeper, I have the following test case:

```
[Property]
public void some_test(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode)
```

Now, I only want `httpStatusCode` which are failures, how do I achieve that using FsCheck?  I have the following code:

```
Prop.ForAll<HttpStatusCode>(code => new Func<bool>(() => !new HttpResponseMessage(code).IsSuccessStatusCode).When(true)).QuickCheck();
```

But have no idea how to hook that into the `Property` attribute for my test case.  Examples online are fairly convoluted for something so trivial.  Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Would be nice to have something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022463/how-to-exclude-null-value-when-using-fscheck-property-attribute) but for custom objects and custom logic.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `When` method to filter.

Something like:

```
Prop.ForAll<HttpStatusCode>(code => 
    !new HttpResponseMessage(code).IsSuccessStatusCode)
    .When(code is failure)   
)
.QuickCheck();
```